# Ubuntu Core Autostart easy-openvpn client connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, snap, autostart

I have an Ubuntu Core with easy-openvpn SNAP on it and want to connect to a openVPN server.
The connection works with this command:

```
sudo easy-openvpn.connect-server ppm.ovpn
```

Now this should happen on boot. How can I do this? 
Link to SNAP: https://github.com/cmars/easy-openvpn-pkg

Comment: its an issue in the repo:
https://github.com/cmars/easy-openvpn-pkg/issues/7